# how to define a function that counts how many times the words from 'the LM word' list (all words in total) appear in the text?

Tags: python, list, count

```py
fhand= open (r"Apple - 2019.txt") 
lines = fhand.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)

LMword= [apple, company, numbers]
```

how to go further to answer the question: how to define a function that counts how many times the words from 'the LM word' list (all words in total) appear in the 'apple' text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the total count (for all words):

```
c=sum([apple.count(i) for i in LMword])
```

Comment: You can if you have more than 15 rep